# Are there any reason why people use this syntax instead of the normal function one?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim mergeSettings = New JsonMergeSettings With {.MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union}
```

I want to create a new JsonMergeSettings. I want to initialize the setting by making `.MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union`

But this is weird.

Why not have a constructor that take MergeArrayHandling enum as parameter?

Yes, there is no such constructor it seems.

So does that mean we can initialize any private variables in a class? Any users of the class can initialize any private variables?

Or maybe only on public variables?

In which case the whole code is pretty much equivalent with

```
    Dim mergeSettings = New JsonMergeSettings ()
    mergeSettings.MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
```

But why the advance notation with  `With {.MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union}`

Why not just use simpler notation like assigning it separately? Are there plus and minus?

Comment: [How to: Declare an Object by Using an Object Initializer (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/how-to-declare-an-object-by-using-an-object-initializer)

Comment: I would go with personal preference.  Some just like the simple one liner while others prefer being more verbose.  Myself I prefer the one liner equivalent when coding in C#, but then in vb.net a little bit more verbose where I've got the With code block

Comment: It's all very well setting each property individually after initialising a local variable but that option isn't available for fields, object initialisers are a great step forward there.

Comment: So initializer basically means after you create the object you initialize the public variable one by one.